# WTForms: I am binding each field on an object individually is there a way to bind the object to the form all at once?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wtforms

I am writing an application in Google App Engine. Previously on `POST` I was binding the submission data as follows:

```
form_data = {
    'fname': self.form.fname.data.strip(),
    'lname': self.form.lname.data.strip(),
    'phone': self.form.phone.data.strip(),
    'email': self.form.email.data.strip().lower(),
    ... (lots more lines like this on long forms)
```

Then I found the one line `populate_obj()` method and I was able to consolidate this into the following line.

```
self.form.populate_obj(customer)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in reverse? I am pulling a `Customer` object out of storage and I want to bind it to the form. The code below functions but is unwieldy.

```
customer = # get customer from storage

self.form.fname.data = customer.fname
self.form.lname.data = customer.lname
self.form.phone.data = customer.phone
self.form.email.data = customer.email
... (lots more lines like this on long forms)
```

Is there something like `populate_form()` that would allow me to bind the object to the form all at once instead of each field individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Form` class constructor has a three keyword arguments.

- `formdata` that takes the form data from the wire, coerces it, and binds it to the form
- `data` which takes a `MultiDict` with keys that correspond to the form's fields, does not perform coercion, and binds to the form.
- `obj` which takes object with attributes that correspond to the form's fields and bind's the values associated with those attributes to the correct form fields.

To do what you are describing you just need to supply your object to the `obj` keyword when you instantiate the form

### code sample

```
from collections import namedtuple                    

from wtforms import Form                              
from wtforms import IntegerField                      
from wtforms import TextField                         

# create some People                                  
Person= namedtuple('person', ['id', 'fname', 'lname'])
p1 = Person(1, 'bob', 'barker')                       

class TestForm(Form):                                 
    id = IntegerField('id')                           
    fname =TextField('lname')                         
    lname =TextField('lname')                         

# Build form and print                                
test_form = TestForm(obj=p1)                          

# test print                                          
print(test_form.id)                                   
print(test_form.fname)                                
print(test_form.lname)                                                                                        
print(test_form.data)
```

### test print

```
<input id="id" name="id" type="text" value="1">
<input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value="bob">
<input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" value="barker">
{'lname': 'barker', 'id': 1, 'fname': 'bob'}
```

The only thing you have to consider is that `obj` does not coerce types. So if you supply the string `'1'` to an `IntegerField` and try to validate your validators will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the well informed answer.  I've attempted to use the `obj` keyword per above.  I've updated my question to reflect this.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have several problems. Just import `UserProfileForm` don't make it a `cached_property`. In the scope of your `def get` method create a variable `form = UserProfileForm(obj=user)` and put it in the context `context = {'form' : form}`

Comment: Also consider following the appengine docs for creating a `def post` method in your `Handler` this is where you should be pulling the form in its wire format `self.request.POST`  and feeding it to the `formdata` keyword before validating it.

Comment: That did the trick.  I was getting an "object not callable" error when trying to use the cached form.  I've unhitched from that and I'm now putting the local form into my context dictionary.  Works great.  Thanks!  I'd give you +2 if I could.